# Is variable inside of llvm BasicBlock visible for others?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Suppose we have a Function named `hello.world`, which contains two BasicBlock `bb.1` and `bb.2`, for example:

```
i32 @hello.world(i32 %x)
bb.1:
  %a = i32 %x
bb.2:
  %b = i32 %a
  ret i32 %b
```

Is variable `%a` in `bb.1` visible for `%b` in `bb.2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid, because `bb.1` doesn't end with a terminator instruction. Have it end with `br label %bb.2` and the answer would be yes.

Strictly speaking, variables defined in the given BB are visible from all BBs that are **dominated by** the given one.

Comment: Being a successor is not enough, the block defining the register must also dominate the block using it.